# Python neural network accuracy - correct implementation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I wrote a simple neural net/MLP and I'm getting some strange accuracy values and wanted to double check things.

This is my intended setup: features matrix with 913 samples and 192 features (913,192). I'm classifying 2 outcomes, so my labels are binary and have shape (913,1). 1 hidden layer with 100 units (for now). All activations will use tanh and all losses use l2 regularization, optimized with SGD

The code is below. It was writtin in python with the Keras framework (http://keras.io/) but my question isn't specific to Keras

```
input_size = 192
hidden_size = 100
output_size = 1
lambda_reg = 0.01
learning_rate = 0.01
num_epochs = 100
batch_size = 10

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_size, hidden_size, W_regularizer=l2(lambda_reg), init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(hidden_size, output_size, W_regularizer=l2(lambda_reg), init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))

sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd, class_mode="binary")

history = History()

model.fit(features_all, labels_all, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=num_epochs, show_accuracy=True, verbose=2, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[history])
score = model.evaluate(features_all, labels_all, show_accuracy=True, verbose=1)
```

I have 2 questions:

This is my first time using Keras, so I want to double check that the code I wrote is actually correct for what I want it to do in terms of my choice of parameters and their values etc.

Using the code above, I get training and test set accuracy hovering around 50-60%. Maybe I'm just using bad features, but I wanted to test to see what might be wrong, so I manually set all the labels and features to something that should be predictable:

```
labels_all[:500] = 1
labels_all[500:] = 0
features_all[:500] = np.ones(192)*500
features_all[500:] = np.ones(192)
```

So I set the first 500 samples to have a label of 1, everything else is labelled 0. I set all the features manually to 500 for each of the first 500 samples, and all other features (for the rest of the samples) get a 1

When I run this, I get training accuracy of around 65%, and validation accuracy around 0%. I was expecting both accuracies to be extremely high/almost perfect - is this incorrect? My thinking was that the features with extremely high values all have the same label (1), while the features with low values get a 0 label

Mostly I'm just wondering if my code/model is incorrect or whether my logic is wrong

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that library, so I can't tell you if this is correctly implemented, but it looks legit.

I think your problem lies with activation function - tanh(500)=1 and tanh(1)=0.76. This difference seem too small for me. Try using -1 instead of 500 for testing purposes and normalize your real data to something about [-2, 2]. If you need full real numbers range, try using linear activation function. If you only care about positive half on real numbers, I propose softplus or ReLU. I've checked and all those functions are provided with Keras.

You can try thresholding your output too - answer 0.75 when expecting 1 and 0.25 when expecting 0 are valid, but may impact you accuracy.

Also, try tweaking your parameters. I can propose (basing on my own experience) that you'd use:

- learning rate = 0.1
- lambda in L2 = 0.2
- number of epochs = 250 and bigger
- batch size around 20-30
- momentum = 0.1
- learning rate decay about 10e-2 or 10e-3

I'd say that learning rate, number of epochs, momentum and lambda are the most important factors here - in order from most to least important.

PS. I've just spotted that you're initializing your weights uniformly (is that even a word? I'm not a native speaker...). I can't tell you why, but my intuition tells me that this is a bad idea. I'd go with random initial weights.

Comment: Data should be scaled to zero mean and unit variance usually.

Comment: Data should be scaled so that your method gives best results. What you said is a good rule of thumb, but if he wants to use tanh, variance bigger than 1 **may** be a better idea.

Comment: oh of course, you're absolutely correct. I didn't even think about the value after passing through the tanh function. A followup question: I'm using scipy zscore to standardize the features (x - xmean / sd). Is this sufficient? Because in the case of extreme scores, the value will extend beyond the bounds of [-2,2]. What's a better way to actually normalize my features to within a certain range?

Comment: Do you know aby boundaries of your features? Can they be negative? Without additional knowledge it's had to tell how should you normalize them.

Comment: its hard to say what the boundaries are right now because I'm still at the stage of building up the model and choosing (adding/removing features) to improve the fit. As of right now there are some feature that are negative, and the range is [-15,15]. I'm guessing for tanh I should normalize to allow for negative values right? Given tanh output values of 0 come from inputs < 0? Whereas for logistic function I should just normalize to [0,1]?

Comment: I think we're getting out of scope ot this question. Look for questions on data normalization and if needed - ask another one, with as many details as possible, comments are not enough for such subject ;) I'll help if I know how, but there is too much content in not enough text in this discussion and some important details are probably left out of here.